# Buscar registros duplicados, cambiarlos y volver unicos en MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Tengo un problema, tengo datos de una tabla que están duplicados, dentro están los siguientes campos `id, empresa, actividad, compañia` necesito que el campo `empresa` sea único, genero una consulta para saber que cuantos y cuales están duplicados y necesito eliminar. Hice la consulta y me arroja los siguientes resultados **(Lo hice así porque no supe como poner una tabla o mejor organizado espero hacerme entender)**:

```
Empresa | Compañia  | Total
Empr1   | Compañia2 | 2
Empr2   | Compañia3 | 4
Empr3   | Compañia1 | 1
```

Ahora necesito que la empresa tenga solo un registro por compañía ¿Como lo logro? o tal vez Que la empresa tenga solo un registro sin importar la compañía ¿Como lo logro?

Esto es para poder volver en campo `empresa` único.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Hay algun problema con regenerar esa tabla de cero? porque lo que hiciste es la solucion si insertas ese resultado en una tabla nueva.

Comment: Hola, pues tiene muchos registros la tabla, y segun como entiendo tu pregunta si creo una nueva tabla, con esta consulta se pasaria de una tabla1 a una tabla2 la informacion tal como esta en la tabla1 ¿no?

Comment: Que quiere decir muchos registros? estamos hablando de millones? y si. Si creas una nueva tabla con el resultado de esta consulta, pues.. tendrias una nueva tabla. No termino de entender que quisiste decir.

Comment: realice esta consulta `SELECT empresa,compania, COUNT(*) Total
FROM tabla
GROUP BY empresa
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` en PHPMyAdmin pero me sale esta advertencia _La selección actual no contiene una columna única. La edición de la grilla y los enlaces de copiado, eliminación y edición no están disponibles_ como genero esta consulta y que los resultados se guarden en una nueva tabla?

Comment: No entiendo que tiene que ver esa consulta y esa advertencia con el problema.

Answer (score 2):

Hola te invito que analices el siguiente ejemplo, es ilustrativo para que puedas resolver tu problema:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
  Empresa varchar(10),
  Compania varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Empr1', 'Compania2')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Empr1', 'Compania2')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Empr2', 'Compania3')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Empr2', 'Compania3')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Empr2', 'Compania3')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Empr2', 'Compania3')
INSERT INTO Test VALUES ('Empr3', 'Compania1')

DELETE TablaDerivada
  FROM (SELECT
    Empresa,
    Compania,
    Repetidos = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Empresa ORDER BY Compania)
  FROM Test) AS TablaDerivada
WHERE Repetidos > 1

SELECT * FROM Test
```

La magia esta dentro del FROM que esta en la setencia del DELETE, el cual realiza una particion por empresa y ordena por compañia, como a cada compañia le asigna un numero y todos son el mismo al final (esta particion representa el campo "Repetidos") en el where especificas que borre aquellos registros donde el campo repetidos sea mayor a uno.

Answer (score 0):

Me guiare de la respuesta de `@BytesMan` pero lo haré de otra manera con [Common Table Expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html):

```
WITH Test_CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Empresa ORDER BY Compania) AS Duplicado FROM Test
)
DELETE FROM Test_CTE WHERE Duplicado > 1;
SELECT * FROM Test;
```